# Why does perl get a "true" for this if statement

Tags: perl, if-statement

I am new to perl and recently found an problem which I cannot figure out.

Here is my code

```
my ($a, $b, $c);
$a = 1.11;
$b = 2.22;
$c = 0;

if ( (0, 0, 0) == ($a, $b, $c))
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

And the result looks really interesting.
If I assign $c = 0 (while $a and $b are not equal 0), then this if statement returns true, but I tried to set either $a or $b equals to 0, then this statement returns false.

The purpose of this statement is to check if all of $a, $b, $c are zeros, but seems whenever $c = 0 , it returns true, who can solve this for me?

Comment: did you try this with `use strict` and `use warnings`?

Comment: yes, I did, but still the same thing

Comment: Didn't you get a warning about "Useless use of private variable in void context"? As is, your code is only doing `if ($c == 0)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`==` forces scalar context. A list (not to be confused with an array!) in scalar context is its very last element. Therefore you're effectively comparing 0 == $c which is true if and only if $c itself is 0.

However, this doesn't answer the question why this doesn't work if `$a` or `$b` are 0. I'm pretty sure that it has something to do with `$a` and `$b` being special variables (they're used e.g. in `sort`). If you'd have used other variable names, e.g. `(0, 0, 0) == ($var1, $var2, $c)` then the content of `$var1` and `$var2` would indeed not have mattered.

In that case `use warnings` would have given you a clue: `Useless use of private variable in void context`. This refers to the fact that both `$var1` and `$var2` are part of a list but not that list's last element, and therefore their values don't matter at all in the statement.

Comment: Package vars $a and $b being special is completely irrelevant. In fact, he's using lexical $a and $b which aren't special. It returns true if $c is 0 and false if $c isn't zero. If it returned false, it's because $c wasn't zero, not because he used $a and $b.

Comment: The list on the left `($a,$b,$c)` is evaluated in scalar context, so it becomes just `$c`.

Comment: I know. When I tried out his original example of setting `$a` or `$b` to zero the result was indeed always false -- or so I thought. Of course I cannot reproduce it anymore, so I guess I was imaging it (or `$c` was always set to non-zero when I played around with the other two). That's what my second paragraph refers to, me thinking I could actually reproduce his weird effect.

Answer (score 1):

you should change the if condition to:

```
return ( ($a == 0) and ($b == 0) and ($c == 0) ) ? 1 : 0;
```

There is not "true" and "false" special words in Perl.
If you have perl 5.10+, this may helps you:

```
my @x = qw(1 0 0);
my @zeros = qw(0 0 0);

return ( @x ~~ @zeros ) ? 1 : 0 ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've defined 2 constants for true and false statement at the begging of the code

use constant { true => 1, false => 0 };

Comment: As perl has more than one 'false' value and very many 'true' values, setting up constants may lead you into bad habits.  Instead of testing for `$x == true` or `$x == false` test for `$x` or `!$x`.

Comment: Agree with @tjd here. `return @x ~~ @zeros;` is sufficient